# Discount Codes Stop Working After a Day

Tags: cividiscount

We currently have CiviCRM 4.4.6 installed with Drupal 7.36. Our version of CiviDiscount is 2.5.

Our issue is as stated in the title. Our discount codes stop working after about a day. It will start giving us fatal errors, the most recent being "/civi_extensions/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/cividiscount.php on line 848".

If we delete the offending discount code and replace it either with the same code or a new one, it will work for a brief period before doing the same thing. This is becoming problematic as we have quite a few upcoming events that need discounts applied to them.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or related to the amount of discount codes we have in the system (~65).

It should be noted that we are in the process of upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7 and have a dev site up, however I haven't had a chance to see if 2.5 is a problem on that installation as well. We'll ideally be upgrading CiviDiscount to the latest version for CiviCRM 4.7, but until then, I need a solution to our current installation.

Comment: Hi there!  You're unlikely to get unpaid help on an old/unsupported version of both CiviCRM and CiviDiscount.  However, you increase your chances by sharing your expanded debugging information.  In CiviCRM, please go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save".  Repeat the problem that caused your error, and you'll see much a much more detailed error.  Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debugging/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: I cleared out some of the old discount codes and we don't seem to be running into the issue anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version seems to have fixed the problem.